# Ansible installation without root

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to install Ansible on Linux as normal user(without root access), Any suggestions, helpful information is appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: This is off topic here because it's not programming related...but honestly, it would be off topic everywhere else, too, because it's not asking a specific technical question (like, "I tried to install ansible as a normal user and I received the following error message, can you help me understand it?").

Comment: you can use the `virtualenv` to install the ansible without root user.

Answer (score 1):

Use `virtualenv` to install `ansible` inside your home directory.